# Cannot receive request body in KTOR application

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have created a simple KTOR application where I have a server module and another client module that is calling the server. Server is running on port 8080 and client is running on port 8081. Here is the code :-
Route.kt (server)

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {

    val service by closestDI().instance<Service>()

    routing {
        post("/demoRoute") {
            log.info("demoRoute called!")
            val data: MyDataClass = call.receive()
            log.info("Calling service")

            // Function written to return a custom API response
            call.fireHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, HttpStatusCode.OK, "success", service.demoFunction(data))
        }
    }
}
```

Client.kt

```
class Client{
    private var client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = JacksonSerializer {
                dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            }
        }
    }

    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()


    suspend fun callRoute(data: MyDataClass): HttpResponse {
        val payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data)
        val response: HttpResponse = client.post {
            url("http://0.0.0.0:8080/demoRoute")
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            body = payload
        }
        return response
    }
}
```

`demoRoute called!` is being printed in the logs but from the `call.receive()` statement, it is skipping all the instructions and directly returns an API Response. I cannot see `Calling service` in my logs. Normally, `call.receive()` works but it is not working in this case. However, when I add `log(call.receive())`, the data received gets printed. When I try to print the `data` variable, nothing happens and the instruction gets skipped. Why would this happen?

Comment: sure you don't have any exceptions? Try catching it with `try`/`catch`. First thought is that Ktor fails to deserialize an object, and `log(call.receive())` will just print a string without deserializing.

Comment: Thanks @PylypDukhov! I used try/catch and logged the exception. It seems there was a problem in the deserialization of a date object. Solved the problem, now it is working!